# Return forfiles result if it finds a duplicate

Tags: batch-file

I don't know how should I title my problem but here's what I'm trying to do:

- I want to search for duplicates in the directory (which is from the input)
- Then get the number of duplicates files
- Here's where I'm stuck, if there's is no duplicate files, it should echo out "No duplicate files found", my idea is using `>nul|set fileError="No duplicate files found"`
- I'm confused where should i placed it because I'm looping through the results.
- To be direct, if there is no duplicate files [filenames] then it should echo "No duplicate files found".

Here's what I did:

```
set findFiles=0
for /f %%A in ('FORFILES /P "%filePath%" /S /M "%fileName%" /C "cmd /c echo @path"') do (
  set /a findFiles+=1
  echo %findFiles% - %%~A
)
```

Update: As to clarify what I wanted, My batch file should return the list of duplicate files if the result is greater than 1, if the return list is only one then it should echo out "No duplicate files found".

Comment: If you really have a need to `Echo` your results within the `For /F` loop structure then you need to use `delayed expansion` or at the very least `Call`! Then consider not using `ForFiles`, which adds additional layer(s) of unnecessary `cmd.exe` instances, _and you're not really using any of its features_. Instead you should look into using a `For /R` loop or stick with the `For /F` but use `Where` or even `Dir` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Based on my comments here are some examples for you.

First using your `ForFiles` method and `delayed expansion`:

```bat
For /F "Delims==" %%A In ('"(Set file[) 2>Nul"') Do Set "%%A="
Set "i=0"
SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion
For /F "Delims=" %%A In (
    'ForFiles /P "%filePath%" /S /M "%fileName%" /C "Cmd /C Echo @Path" 2^>Nul'
) Do Set /A i+=1 & Set "file[!i!]=%%~A" 
If %i% Equ 0 Echo File %fileName% not found in %filePath% & GoTo End
If %i% Equ 1 Echo No duplicates of %fileName% found in %filePath% & GoTo End
For /L %%A In (1 1 %i%) Do Echo [%%A]!file[%%A]!
:End
Pause
```

---

Using `For /F` with `Dir` and `delayed expansion`:

```bat
For /F "Delims==" %%A In ('"(Set file[) 2>Nul"') Do Set "%%A="
Set "i=0"
SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion
For /F "Delims=" %%A In ('Dir /B /S /A-D "%filePath%\%fileName%" 2^>Nul'
) Do Set /A i+=1 & Set "file[!i!]=%%A" 
If %i% Equ 0 Echo File %fileName% not found in %filePath% & GoTo End
If %i% Equ 1 Echo No duplicates of %fileName% found in %filePath% & GoTo End
For /L %%A In (1 1 %i%) Do Echo [%%A]!file[%%A]!
:End
Pause
```

You could also use `Where` instead of `Dir` changing its line `4`to:

```bat
For /F "Delims=" %%A In ('"Where /R "%filePath%" "%fileName%" 2>Nul"'
```

You could use `RoboCopy` changing line `4` to the following two lines:

```bat
Set "RCO=/S /L /XJ /R:0 /FP /NS /NC /NP /NDL /NJH /NJS"
For /F "Tokens=*" %%A In ('RoboCopy "%filePath%" Null "%fileName%" %RCO%'
```

Or possibly a `For /R` option changing line `4` to:

```bat
For /R "%filePath%" %%A In ("%fileName%?"
```

*The `For /R` version is a little strange because it has to use a wildcard, whilst this could be problematic, it may be useful however should you doubt whether your file has the `.doc` or `.docx` extension; (it should match both)*

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I tried most of your answer but it didn't achieve my objective.
Supposed I search for "batch_exercise.bat" with given directory, if "batch_exercise.bat" is only one in that directory it should echo "No duplicates found" but I get this output
[1]C:\Users\Infinite Regression\Desktop\project_os\batch_exercise.bat

Comment: Well you should have made it clear in your question, that you were looking for a number of GEq 2 or GTR 1 for a duplicate in the same directory. My assumption from your question was that you had a file held elsewhere as the variable and you were trying to determine if the target directory tree held a duplicate filename. Please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/48474390/edit) in order to make it clear.

Comment: Question updated, anyway I tried to work it out by comparing the count files with GTR 1 but it also echo out the "C:\Users\Infinite".

Comment: @RicardoRaz, I have rewritten my answer to match your clarified question parameters.

Comment: I am confused what does line 1 does aside from setting a variable?

Comment: It doesn't set a variable, it un-sets, _(un-defines)_, any existing variables beginning with `file[`. That way you ensure there are no potential future collisions with pre-existing variables.